# Bootstrap loader synchronization error MSP430F249

Tags: embedded, msp430, texas-instruments

I have a problem when I program code via `BSL` to `MSP430F249 MCU`. I'm using `bsl2demo.exe` to program. The error is:

> ERROR: Synchronization failed! Device with boot loader connected?

---

[image][image]

HERE IS SCHEMATIC MY DEGISN. YOU CHECK IT
[image]

Comment: Are you sure the hardware is connected properly?

Comment: Yes. I am using FT232BL USB chip and MSP430F249. In MSP430F249, P1.1 and P2.2 are transmitting and receiving data. TCK and RST/NMI is supplied for sequence entry BSL

Comment: Do you know that there is a bootloader in this device?  Is it clocked properly at the expected speed?  Are you specifying the right virtual port for the FT232?  Have you been able to program any other hardware such an an eval board using this method?